# Docker postgres image mount already host mounted cifs share

Tags: postgresql, docker

My centos 7 docker host is mounting a cifs share, the fstab entry looks like:

```
//hostname/postgres-data /var/lib/postgres-data cifs
credentials=/root/creds_database,uid=postgres,gid=postgres,forceuid,forcegid,context=system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0
0 0
```

Then when starting my postgres container my run command is

```
docker run --name postgres-image -v /var/lib/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

The container runs and then instantly exits.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working? What is the best way to get diagnostic information to trouble shoot this issue?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the PostgreSQL log file to see what problems caused it to abort the startup.

You should not run PostgreSQL on a CIFS file system; last time I checked that did not fsync files properly, so it will cause database corruption. At least make dead sure that fsync is working properly.